# Convert money data type to string and add a few leading zeros

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like convert money data type to string and add a few leading zeros.

Let say the money cell displays

```
2345,56
45,23
```

And I need it to convert it like

```
0000000234556
0000000004513
```

The final length is always 13.

Which formula should be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
=TEXT(A1*100;"0000000000000")
```

Where: A1 is the cell with the value and `"0000000000000"` is 13 `0`s